# Add class and remove on button click in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am looking for more sophisticated way how to add class and then remove from other divs.
I have on Wordpress site Fluent Forms plugin and I want to add class to image if I click on radio button, if I click on second option remove class from first selected option and add class to actual selected.

```
<div class="image-container">

<div class="image-heading-hide image-container-1">
    <p>Sekcia 1</p>
    <img src="https://calc.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/police_1.png" alt="" id="image-1">
</div>

<div class="image-heading-hide image-container-2">
    <p>Sekcia 2</p>
    <img src="https://calc.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/police_1.png" alt="" id="image-2">
</div>

<div class="image-heading-hide image-container-3">
    <p>Sekcia 3</p>
    <img src="https://calc.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/police_1.png" alt="" id="image-3">
</div>

<div class="image-heading-hide image-container-4">
    <p>Sekcia 4</p>
    <img src="https://calc.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/police_1.png" alt="" id="image-4">
</div>

<div class="image-heading-hide image-container-5">
    <p>Sekcia 5</p>
    <img src="https://calc.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/police_1.png" alt="" id="image-5">
</div>
```

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".fluentform .ff-el-group.ff_list_buttons .ff-el-form-check input[value='Priestor 1']").click(function () {
        jQuery('#image-2').removeClass('border');
        jQuery('#image-1').addClass('border');
    });

    jQuery(".fluentform .ff-el-group.ff_list_buttons .ff-el-form-check input[value='Priestor 2']").click(function () {
        jQuery('#image-1').removeClass('border');
        jQuery('#image-2').addClass('border');  
    });
});
</script>
```

Click function depend on value(1,2,3 etc) of input on form plugin
.fluentform .ff-el-group.ff_list_buttons .ff-el-form-check input[value='Priestor 1']"

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Can you please share the exact code here because your HTML and JS code do not match.

Comment: I would suggest you maintain a common class for all the image elements instead of a unique Id and on click or change event remove all the classes of the image using common class has added on image element and relate your radion button using an index or this element to the image element and add class to the specific image element

Answer (score 0):

Use wild card on image id to remove all class `$("[id^=image-]").removeClass('border');`. Get`radio` button value and split to get number. Based upon that number add your class on image.

Sigle radio button change works. No need to repeat the code.

Demo example.

```js
var $radios = $('input[name=opt]').change(function() {
  var value = $radios.filter(':checked').val();
  var num = value.split(' ')[1];
  $("[id^=image-]").removeClass('border');
  $('#image-' + num).addClass('border');

});
```

```css
.border {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Priestor 1" />
<input type="radio" name="opt" class="radio" value="Priestor 2" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image-container">

  <div class="image-heading-hide image-container-1">
    <p>Sekcia 1</p>
    <img src="https://calc.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/police_1.png" alt="" id="image-1">
  </div>

  <div class="image-heading-hide image-container-2">
    <p>Sekcia 2</p>
    <img src="https://calc.ffd.sk/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/police_1.png" alt="" id="image-2">
  </div>

</div>
```